# Django Max count of foreign key set

Tags: django, orm

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    pass

class Article(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

`b = Blog.objects.filter(...)`

Given `b`, is it possible to find with a single query the highest count of associated articles?

I could do that by iterating:

```
max_count = 0
for blog in b:
    if b.article_set.count() > max_count:
        max_count = b.article_set.count()
```

Is there a more efficient way that uses the ORM/SQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate, like:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Max

max_count = Blog.objects.annotate(
    narticle=Count('article')
).aggregate(
    max_count=Max('narticle')
)['max_count']
```

This will generate a query like:

```
SELECT MAX(narticle)
FROM (
    SELECT blog.id AS col1, COUNT(article.id) AS narticle
    FROM blog
    LEFT OUTER JOIN article ON article.blog_id = blog.id
    GROUP BY blog.id
) subquery
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! The annotate doesn't work: django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'article' into field. I also tried with article_set.

Comment: @Saturnix: did you specify a `related_name` in your `ForeignKey`? What choices does Django suggest?

Comment: @Saturnix: normally Django will say "possible choices are ..."

Comment: My bad, I was spelling the model name with the class capitalization instead of the one from "possible choices" (all lower case). It works now, thanks a lot!